# bottle httprequest object manual update

Tags: python-3.x, bottle

Just yesterday got that I can't use one function that would return one template depending on cookies, and wich would be called by different methods of different routes. The reason is all the `response.set_cookie()` are not applied to main Bottle object HTTPResponse before the method finishes serving current route. So the question is there a way to explicitly cast application of all the changes to HTTPResponse object, so i could avoid passing complex structures to subroutines and etc. 
Thank you for help!

UPD: there is a `response.set_cookie('temp', 'sampletext')` line for example. And then i am calling subroutine and it calls another one and so on. So In each of them i won't have `request.get_cookie('temp')` returning `'sampletext'`. Because changes to cookies wasn't applied yet. There are in the Bottle.py code you can find following code:

```
class HTTPResponse(Response, BottleException):
    def __init__(self, body='', status=None, headers=None, **more_headers):
        super(HTTPResponse, self).__init__(body, status, headers, **more_headers)

    def apply(self, response):
        response._status_code = self._status_code
        response._status_line = self._status_line
        response._headers = self._headers
        response._cookies = self._cookies
        response.body = self.body
```

that seems to be executing once per request and changes from httpresponse objects are appliied to the response object only on finish of the rout's serving method termination. 
I am asking if there is a way to apply changes to response object manually, during the route's serving method evaluation.

Comment: I don't understand your question; perhaps a small code example would help?

Comment: updated the question for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am asking if there is a way to apply changes to response object manually, during the route's serving method evaluation.

No.

I'm not completely sure, but it sounds like you just want to store some state during a request.

The mechanism for this is to simply set attributes on the request object.  E.g.

```
@route(...)
def index_page():
    ...
    request.mydata = 'hello'
    ...
```

This is completely independent of cookies.  If you need both, just set both; one on the request object and the other on the response.

Comment: well, it solves my problems but not answers the question)) thank you

Comment: Edited to answer your question.